# How can I use "Expression.Not" with text field?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

How can I use "Expression.Not" with text field?

I need to select all records from NHQuestionCount except "ktest"

for example this code return runtime error

```
NHQuestionCount[] stats = NHQuestionCount.FindAll(Order.Asc("NameFull"), Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("NameFull", "ktest")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the rest of your code, but your use of Expression is exactly right.